# What would happen to enormous indestructible ruins after 400 million years?

Tags: physics, geology, architecture, tectonics

Suppose you had ruins (and I use the term lightly) that could survive nearly any disaster and any erosion. How likely are they to be buried, subsumed into the mantle, or end up at the bottom of the ocean/tops of mountains? I emphasize that these structures are practically indestructible (the buildings are made out of unobstructible space, as in space space, empty room space. The walls are just solid dimensional space. Congealed by curving space and bound to gravity the same way spacetime warps with gravity.) They've only been abandoned for so long. Pristine, like a lego in a sandbox. They aren't small, either, some are larger than the Jeddah Tower. Original orientation need not apply, some of these are definitely flipped upside down as they tumble over the continental plates.

Comment: How *heavy* are those structures? How are they anchored to the underlying rocks? As it stands the question needs more detail in order to become answerable.

Comment: You'd need to pick a comparable spot on Earth for us to tell you this. Are they near the edge of a tectonic plate, or in the middle of one in a stable location? Is it in the northern climate, where they'd be subject to glaciation? Are the roads indestructible, or just the buildings? You're talking about a LOT of erosion in that time period. the Devil's Tower was a volcano only 50 million years ago.

Comment: VTC Too Story-Based. How is anyone supposed to know if your fictional construction methods designed to be all-but-indestructible are likely to end up (e.g.) at the bottom of an ocean after any amount of time? In reality, whether or not they will be destroyed or buried or anything else will be a consequence of [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609) (aka storybuilding). Choose what you want to have happen to your godlike buildings and we can help you determine how to achieve that goal. Asking an open-ended question "what would happen next?" is off-topic.

Comment: Narrative need not apply, it's simply a setting question. @JBH

Comment: Quinn, I actually don't see how this is a simple setting question at all. The answer to your query depends on where you put the indestructible object. That's textbook narrativity.

Comment: I agree with @elemtilas. You're not asking about a chemical reaction in a controlled environment. Your question is entirely dependent on your story because it's surrounded by unpredictable chaos. The ruins will survive if you want them to. They won't if you don't. There is no best answer here. No correct answer either. (Prohibited by the [help/dont-ask]). It's also a hypothetical question (also prohibited by the [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: So, in order to properly address your question in a non-narrative manner, I think it would be helpful if you described what *"unobstructible space, as in space space, empty room space. The walls are just solid dimensional space. Congealed by curving space and bound to gravity the same way spacetime warps with gravity"* actually means. How does this congealed space interact with ordinary matter and forces as we understand them? It seems like your congealed space interacts, but clarity would be nice. Either that, or leave the object itself undefined. Lastly, since SE likes (cont)

Comment: (cont) focused questions, it might behoove you to pick a specific location in your world and ask about that. If you wanted to broaden your problem a bit, you could ask for a comparison of a reasonable number of specific location types.

Answer (score 6):

> the buildings are made out of unobstructible space, as in space space,
> empty room space. The walls are just solid dimensional space.

**Once unmoored, these buildings will float away**

Space not containing matter will have less mass than space containing matter, it is safe to say.  Buoyancy is determined by volume and mass.  Space occupying volume but not containing matter will be buoyant in a gas atmosphere, which is space containing matter (as gas).

When the connections between this "solid dimensional space" and the normal terrestrial substrate are disrupted, the structures will float away into the sky.  These connections have a constant force working on them - the buoyancy of the tethered empty space buildings which is actually the atmosphere trying to get underneath them.  They will float and float away pretty fast if they are big; they are the proverbial vacuum balloon. The speed of ascent will be limited by air resistance they encounter.  Massless and unaffected by the gravity of sun or Earth, they will leave the atmosphere.   They will continue on a trajectory determined by the vector conferred by their buoyancy combined with the vector of the Earths own movement.

Comment: Nice answer, I wonder about the trajectory or fate of this slow moving massless structure once it has left Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: I can science-mumbojumbo why it acts like normal matter. The point isn't what it's made of, it's what would happen to ANY structure that could survive that long without changing.

Comment: @Quinn - the point is that what happens to normal matter on the surface of the earth depends on the density of that matter.  Rather than ask about that I ran with zero density - empty space.

Answer (score 3):

I may be answering this wrong, but assuming they are essentially like Lego bricks set atop a giant world sized sandbox of sorts... well these indestructible foreign pieces would roll and move without being broken up. As they as gravity-bound they will not float away... but the mass of the ruins does not apply? So essentially, it's almost like Super Mario Galaxy, as long as nothing will pull the ruins into the planet, it can float about barring what would normally be impossible conditions like unstable sand or perhaps even floating on the sea so long as the density 'beneath' exceeds some variable? For the sake of ease, I am going to assume atmospheric density is not counted since the 'float away' surely happens otherwise as Willk refers to.

All assumptions made, the conditions could be ripe for them to never be subducted even at subduction points by them simply by being atop and too large to be sucked under. Sort of like Lego towers being too large to be sucked into even street drains if they cannot be broken up. Placement on successful continental rifts would go a long way for general long-lasting conditions. The presence of billion-year-old rock, while rare with active plate tectonics here on Earth, do exist. Proper modeling could let them essentially and naturally exist on land, even to the point that the rock erodes and sends them tumbling (intact) down the sides of mountains or into a failed rift.

While they would typically be buried by sediment, I suppose even that could be explained. Placed in mountains to start with or embedded with a deep structure much like how modern super skyscrapers are anchored into bedrock (your ruins anchored very deep into the bedrock itself) allowing for even mountains to erode around it, leaving a main entrance high in the air or needing to tunnel into the depths for access. This would be interesting as projections show the Himalayan mountains will be around for over 250 million years as the super continent reforms, and if the rift opens up properly, they could survive eventually being like the Appalachian mountains.

One last point, if the mantle is cooling plate tectonics will cease and if on the last 'cycle' of the system the placed ruin will stand forever if the subduction eventually halts. Though that means the core would stop spinning and solar winds would strip away the atmosphere.... choose the time wisely, I guess? You'd have millions of years by any measure though.